# as3 - converting bitmap back to vector in view

Tags: actionscript-3

So I found a V-CAM source, I am now using it and quite happy however, is it possible to untoggled bitmap when the objects that are bitmapped are viewed by the cam? For instance, lets say I have a vector movieclip with a bunch of vector art, I toggle export as bitmap on the movieclip from my IDE, now would it be possible to add on to my VCAM, that everything in its view (it resizes stage) untoggles or redraws back to vector, while the rest of map/movieclip is still in bitmap? And as the VCAM moves away, what was shifted from bitmap to vector gets shifted back to bitmap?

```
    var camColor: ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
var parentColor: ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
var cX: Number;
var cY: Number;
var sX: Number;
var sY: Number;
this.visible = false;
var oldMode: String = stage.scaleMode;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
cX = stage.stageWidth / 2;
cY = stage.stageHeight / 2;
sX = stage.stageWidth;
sY = stage.stageHeight;
stage.scaleMode = oldMode;
camColor = this.transform.colorTransform;
parentColor = this.parent.transform.colorTransform;
camControl(new Event(Event.ENTER_FRAME));
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, camControl);
addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, resetStage);
function camControl(event: Event): void {
    camColor = this.transform.colorTransform;
    parent.transform.colorTransform = camColor;
    var xScale: Number = sX / this.width;
    var yScale: Number = sY / this.height;
    parent.x = cX - (this.x * xScale);
    parent.y = cY - (this.y * yScale);
    parent.scaleX = xScale;
    parent.scaleY = yScale;
}
function resetStage(event: Event): void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, camControl);
    parent.transform.colorTransform = parentColor;
    parent.scaleX = 1;
    parent.scaleY = 1;
    parent.x = 0;
    parent.y = 0;
}
```

Comment: What the....??? What's the benefit of doing this complication of _bitmap to vector to bitmap_? What's wrong with your current result if you don't do this process (_eg:_ what problem does it solve if done)?

Comment: @VC.One Large maps, don't like the quality of bitmaps, so I want to render in vector through VCAM, while the bg is bitmap or the rest that isn't being viewed. It is kind of like a walking MMO. I want it for a performance boost, since you know having everything else as bitmap fixes the lag, and the user gets to enjoy the good quality they see on screen.

Comment: Or maybe I am thinking of it wrong. Maybe something like a hide all vectors not in the container view?

Comment: Does this [Nintendo 8-bit scrolling article](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1316851183/nesmaker-make-nes-games-no-coding-required/posts/2314558?cursor=21901446) give you a better idea? Also consider using **compression** to keep large small until needed to load. Look at **Zlib** for small sizes. You can [find it here](https://github.com/igniterealtime/XIFF/tree/master/src/org/igniterealtime/xiff/util). It's in a sub-folder so you'll have to download the full [XIFF encoder library](https://github.com/igniterealtime/XIFF) and copy every file in **util** folder to a preferred folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd better use another camera with higher bitmap dimensions (2x-4x) to render those scenes from vector that you feel are too pixelized. In terms of export, just export the character's bitmaps 2x-4x larger, or you can just have it as a vector somewhere in your app, maybe hidden, and do realtime render when needed, or plain have it in your display list as a vector and not a bitmap.

In case you need to have some complex vector form into a bitmap-based engine, you can use realtime bitmap drawing of a single source in various postures/rotations, then use those rendered bitmaps to get performance. Check the game "Enigmata: Stellar War" for this technique, how does it look in the process (hint: when it says "Loading boss" it does all the render behind the scenes).

Getting a vectorized source form bitmaps is a lot more processor consuming than having a ready-made vectorized source stored somewhere. Also you won't get your original vector restored in exact form, as converting a vector to a bitmap is a lossy transformation.